# Wordpress ajax-action failing because of newline in response

Tags: php, ajax, wp-admin, xml

When I'm using the dashboard, for example, adding a category.  The request returns valid XML as expected, but it is prepended with a newline character, causing the `DOMParser()` to fail.

I'm not sure where to proceed for debugging, it happens on one site and not another (different server, different theme).  I've checked, none of the theme's php files have any characters proceeding `<?php` and none end with `?>`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Found a plugin ending with ?> which had a linebreak after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a plugin ending with ?> with a newline after it